# Is it possible to get Yoast primary category from product ID alone

Tags: woocommerce, yoast

Is it possible get Yoast Primary Category from Product ID ($product->get_id()) alone?

I've tried

`$primary_term_id = yoast_get_primary_term_id( 'product_cat', $product->get_id() );`

but to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

I came up with the same solution as you but also no luck.

I've found a way to get the Primary Category ID from Yoast this way:

```
get_post_meta( $product->get_id(), '_yoast_wpseo_primary_product_cat', true );
```